# *GEMR2D documentation (scalapack)

Tags: documentation, scalapack

Where can I find documentation for the P*GEMR2D routines in Fortran?

---

I've found:

- [Scalapack UG](http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node165.html#SECTION04851000000000000000)
- [Undocumented related source](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d9/d30/pdgemr2_8c_source.html)
- [Unanswered forum post](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=611)

Comment: What sort of documentation are you looking for? It seems like if you follow the Scalapack UG link and click the "Next" button in the upper left a few times, you get call signatures, discussions of the function, and what the arguments mean. All of these pages use Fortran documentation; the first page appears to be empty and looks like there's no documentation, but continuing onwards yields more information.

Comment: "Next" for the UG had what I wanted.  I guess I assumed the blank 'fortran interface' page was a dead end.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll write my comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scalapack UG link brings up a misleading web page. It looks as if there isn't any Fortran documentation, when I suppose the page is instead intended to be a title page. Clicking on the "Next" button in the upper left-hand corner brings you to the first page of Fortran interface documentation for `P_GEMR2D`.

Comment: For example: http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node166.html